# How can i convert json data into php variables?

Tags: php, arrays, json, variables, undefined-index

I have a *json* file which I want to get the data from and use it as *php variables* inside of a loop.

I keep getting Undefined index erros and it just does not work...

**This is my code:**

```php
$file = file_get_contents("csv/products.json",'r');   

    for($i=0;$i<18;$i++){ 

    $datosArray = json_decode($file,true);

    //var_dump($datosArray);

   if (isset ($datosArray)){
    $id =  $datosArray["id"];
    $genderid = $datosArray["sex_id"];
    $dest =  $datosArray["destaque"];
    $cat =  $datosArray["categoria"];
    $marc =  $datosArray["Marca"];
    $name =  $datosArray["nombre"];
    $desc =  $datosArray["descripcion"];
    $pho1 =  $datosArray["photo_id1"];
    $pho2 =  $datosArray["photo_id2"];
    $pho3 =  $datosArray["photo_id3"];
    $dprice = $datosArray["D_price"];
    $oprice =  $datosArray["O_price"];
    }

    ?>
```

**This is what part of my json looks like:**

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "sex_id": 101,
    "destaque": 1,
    "categoria": "Vestidos",
    "Marca": "Marfinno",
    "nombre": "Mono rayas",
    "descripcion": "Mono de rayas con botones y amarre  Marfinno",
    "photo_id1": "Female1.jpg",
    "photo_is2": "Female1.1.jpg",
    "photo_id3": "Female1.2.jpg",
    "D_price": "$100.00",
    "O_price": "$300.00"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "sex_id": 101,
    "destaque": 0,
    "categoria": "Vestidos",
    "Marca": "Marfinno",
    "nombre": "Mono liso",
    "descripcion": "Mono liso con amarre  Marfinno",
    "photo_id1": "Female2.jpg",
    "photo_is2": "Female2.1.jpg",
    "photo_id3": "Female2.2.jpg",
    "D_price": "$100.00",
    "O_price": "$300.00"
  },
```

Thank you.

Comment: What does the `var_dump` show?

Comment: An array... array(54) { [0]=> array(12) { ["id"]=> int(1) ["sex_id"]=> int(101) ["destaque"]=> int(1) ["categoria"]=> string(8) "Vestidos" ["Marca"]=> string(8) "Marfinno" ["nombre"]=> string(10) "Mono rayas" ["descripcion"]=> string(44) "Mono de rayas con botones y amarre Marfinno" ["photo_id1"]=> string(11) "Female1.jpg" ["photo_is2"]=> string(13) "Female1.1.jpg" ["photo_id3"]=> string(13) "Female1.2.jpg" ["D_price"]=> string(7) "$100.00" ["O_price"]=> string(7) "$300.00" } [1]=> array(12)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mistake here:

```
$file = file_get_contents("csv/products.json",'r');
```

Simply put:

```
$file = file_get_contents("csv/products.json");
```

`file_get_contents` does not require a 'r' argument like when you open a file.  See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

---

Then from the comment about the `var_dump`, you have to see that you have an array of arrays.

```
array(54) { 
    [0]=> array(12) { 
        ["id"]=> int(1) 
        ["sex_id"]=> int(101) 
        ["destaque"]=> int(1) 
        ["categoria"]=> string(8) "Vestidos" 
        ["Marca"]=> string(8) "Marfinno" 
        ["nombre"]=> string(10) "Mono rayas" 
        ["descripcion"]=> string(44) "Mono de rayas con botones y amarre Marfinno" 
        ["photo_id1"]=> string(11) "Female1.jpg" 
        ["photo_is2"]=> string(13) "Female1.1.jpg" 
        ["photo_id3"]=> string(13) "Female1.2.jpg" 
        ["D_price"]=> string(7) "$100.00" 
        ["O_price"]=> string(7) "$300.00" 
    } 
    [1]=> array(12) {
        ....
    }
```

So when you want to reference an item, you have to put 2 indexes:

```
...
$id =  $datosArray[$i]["id"];
$genderid = $datosArray[$i]["sex_id"];
...
```

This will work if you keep that portion of code inside the context of the `for` loop.

Comment: I added new content, based on your comment on `var_dump`.

Comment: That is new for me, You have just, saved my life... Thank you so much